# MS-Access - Append Query - Carry MVF

Tags: ms-access, append

Before I start I need to say I know multi-valued fields are a bad way to store data. However, because of the data and what it will be used for it seemed the easiest way and this problem has been bugging me for a short while

I am building a database that has multiple different tables based on Candidates and their specialized job sector

I have multiple queries that take data from one table to another depending on inputted values

I have a table called `TblClient`, which holds all the client names

I have a table called `TblCandidateSupport`, within this table, I have a lookup field that holds multiple values from `TblClient` (only needed so I can see which candidate has been to which clients)

The problem I am having is when I run an append query to the values stored in the multi-valued field to another table called `TblCandidateSupportAvailable`. 
I either get an error "An INSERT INTO query cannot contain a multi-valued field" or only get one value appending when I use.value. 
The value that is appended from the `TblCandidate` will only ever be viewed.

What is the best way to carry the data across?

Comment: See if this discussion helps https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6e8a6eaa-29e5-444c-a107-2b00a628a2e9/update-multi-value-field-in-access. I NEVER use MVF and I NEVER set lookups in table.

Comment: I don't understand reason for duplicating data to multiple tables.